# bootstrap / jquery Smartmenus: wrap around dropdown-menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how can I add a wrap around my submenu. If I add the wrap, the menu is not working anymore.

```
<ul class="nav flex-row smartmenus d-print-none sm" data-smartmenus-id="">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a href="/somepage1.html" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle has-submenu" id="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="" aria-expanded="false">Some page</a>
    <!--<div class="mywrap">-->
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="group" id="" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="" aria-expanded="false">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a href="/somepage1/test.html" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle-submenu has-submenu" id="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="" aria-expanded="false">Test</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    <!--</div>-->
  </li>
</ul>
```